# How to change the qmake path in to [Qt-dir/bin/qmake].

Tags: qt4

I am trying to compile a Qt application through command line in ubuntu.
for me "which qmake " giving /usr/bin. I have given the Qt/bin path in PATH variable. How to change the qmake path in to Qt/bin. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export PATH=/Qt/Bin:$PATH
```

Does that solve your problem? otherwise I don't understand what you mean.